# How to use modules in Firefox addon development

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Trying to create a firefox addon that accesses the browser cookies. Following googled tutorials I've written the following function but looks like the Services.jsm is not accessible?

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var myExtension = {
myListener: function(evt) {

    //I get here
    alert("Received from web page: " +
    evt.target.getAttribute("attribute1") + "/" +
    evt.target.getAttribute("attribute2"));

    //I dont see anything dumped 
    let enum = Services.cookies.getCookiesFromHost("example.com");
    while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
        var cookie = e.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsICookie2);
        dump(cookie.host + ";" + cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value + "\n");
    }

  }
}
document.addEventListener("MyExtensionEvent", function(e) { myExtension.myListener(e); }, false, true);
```

Comment: This is because you have not defined `Ci` you use `Ci` in the while loop. You can replace `Ci` with `Components.interfaces` and it should fix it up. :) If you want to use the `C?` short forms it is typically done by adding to the top: `const {Cc:classes, Cu:utils, Ci:interfaces, Cr:results, CC: Constructor} = Components` as seen in this example here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56824

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart also e should be replaced by enum..I have copy pasted from the official page but looks like they have it wrong. I'm also trying to add a cookie Services.cookies.add('host', '*', 'name', 'val', false, true, false, 0); is this the proper way of doing ti? Please add your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Shakur I didn't catch that `e` and yep you're right it needs to be fixed to `enum`.

I'm not familiar with cookie service, I would have to read up on it but you're on right track.

This is because you have not defined Ci you use Ci in the while loop. You can replace `Ci` with `Components.interfaces` and it should fix it up. :) If you want to use the `C*` short forms it is typically done by adding to the top: `const {Cc:classes, Cu:utils, Ci:interfaces, Cr:results, CC: Constructor} = Components` as seen in this example here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56821/improvements-to-nsizipreader-and-nsiscriptableinputstream/56824#56824